# Geth v1.9.24 - POA - no sealing with period 0 - "Sealing paused, waiting for transactions"

Tags: private-blockchain, poa, clique, geth-clique

I have a private clique network with geth v1.9.24.  1 sealer and 1 node.  With period=0 there is no sealing happening, all transactions go to txpool as pending, and logs show "Sealing paused, waiting for transactions".  With period=1 or period=5 sealing starts happening and all the transactions get sealed in blocks.  When I tried 3 sealers and 3 nodes, the same thing happens with period=0, no sealing.  I created the genesis file using puppeth.

I started the node as follows:
/usr/bin/geth --nousb --allow-insecure-unlock --identity "xxxx" --verbosity "3" --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcvhosts "*" --rpcapi "miner,eth,net,personal,web3" --port "30303" --nodiscover --gcmode "archive" --miner.gasprice "1" --miner.gastarget "8000000000" --miner.gaslimit "9000000000000000" --networkid "830" --ipcpath "/home/eth_user/gethipc/geth.ipc" --unlock "xxxxxxxxxxxx" --password "xxxxxxxxx" --mine --syncmode "full"

I called eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[1], to: eth.coinbase, value: web3.toWei(30, "ether")}) multiple times from the geth console, and each transaction ended up pending in txpool.  eth.accounts[1] was pre-funded, while eth.coinbase (sealer) was not.

I need period=0 to work so that the transactions are sealed very fast when they are submitted, and so that we don't have unnecessary bloat from empty blocks.

Am I missing setting up some parameter in Geth v1.9.24?  This doesn't happen with Geth v1.8.27.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This problem still exists in v1.9.25

Answer (score 1):

In Geth v1.10.1, setting the block numbers for the various forks equal to zero in the genesis file seems to fix the problem.

```
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1337,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 0,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
```

see https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/21951